# Pandas read_csv: Data is not being read from text file (open() reads hex chars)

Tags: python, pandas, character-encoding, text-files

I'm trying to read a text file with `pandas.read_csv`, but data is not being loaded (only a dataframe with `NA` values. The text file contains valid data (I can open it with excel). When I try to read it with `pathlib.Path.open()` it shows lines with Hex codes.

Let me show you what is happening:

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('path/to/my/file.txt')
# This shows an error: Unidecode Error... as usual with windows files
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=str) 
## UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 96: invalid continuation byte

# This imports a dataframe full of null values:
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=str, encoding='latin1') 
print(df)
##           C Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4 Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6  \
## 0     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>   
## 1     <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>  
## ...

# So, what is Python reading? I tried this:
with path.open('r') as f:
    data = f.readline()
print(data)
## 'C\x00e\x00n\x00t\x00r\x00o\x00 \x00B\x00e\x00n\x00e\x00f\x00i\x00c\x00i\x00o\x00s\x00\n
```

And, as I said before, when I open the file with Excel, it shows exactly how it is supposed to look: a text files with values separated by pipes (`|`). So, right now, I'm feeling quite surprised.

What am I missing? Can anyone point me in the right direction? Which is the right encoding?

Comment: try 'encoding='utf-16le''

Comment: @Beatdown Thank you! Just tested it and it worked! Please, add an answer, so I can upvote it! (You just saved my rearside )

Comment: I will do that now. ha, happy to have helped!

Comment: It seems that I can only post once every 30 mins (due to my score I think). I will do it in around 20mins. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This suggests that the encoding of your text file is neither utf-8 nor latin1. Try 'UTF-16 Little Endian' by editing this line..

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, dtype=str, encoding='utf-16le')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It looks like someone is trying to mess with my head! A second file is encoded with UTF-32... at least now I know that it's not my fault any of this 